# scroll to scrape additional details using selenium and beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I have the python code below.  I'm using it to scrape property sale data from zillow.  It uses selenium chrome driver to open a chrome browser.  It then navigates to the property sale url for the zip code.  I then use beautifulsoup to scrape the property details.  The problem I'm having is that in the example below it's only scraping the first 9 properties data.  I think it needs to scroll down and scrape more properties.  Can anyone suggest how to scrape the rest of the properties info?

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


Options

options = Options()

chrome_options = Options() 



#re allows for matching text with regular expressions (including through BeautifulSoup)
#dateutil.parser provies .parse() to convert plain text dates in a variety of formats into datetime objects
import re, dateutil.parser
#BeautifulSoup provide a model for the source HTML
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Webdriver is interface to the selected browser (PhantomJS)
from selenium import webdriver
#Ability to select values in HTML <select> tags
from selenium.webdriver.support import select
import time


from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains, keys

from re import sub

import datetime




def property_details(zip_code):
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("chromedriver"), chrome_options=chrome_options)

    
    zip_url = 'https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/'+str(zip_code)+'_rb/'

    # waits between pulling data
    time.sleep(np.random.randint(low=3, high=7, size=1)[0])
    
    # opens website
    driver.get(zip_url)
    
    # getting page source data
    tstsoup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
    
    
    # getting list of prices

    price_parse=tstsoup.find_all('div',{'class':'list-card-price'})

    price_list=[]

    for x in range(len(price_parse)):

        price_list.append(int(sub(r'[^\d.]', '',price_parse[x].get_text())))
        
    # get address
    
    address_parse=tstsoup.find_all('address',{'class':'list-card-addr'})

    # address_parse[0].get_text()

    address_list=[]

    for i in range(len(address_parse)):

        address_list.append(address_parse[i].get_text())
        
    # get home details

    main_data=tstsoup.find_all('ul',{'class':'list-card-details'})
    detail_list=[]
    for data in main_data:
        d={  i.text.split(" ")[1] : i.text.split(" ")[0] for i in data.find_all("li",class_="")   }
        detail_list.append(d)
        
    # creating dict of property details    
        
    ts=str(datetime.datetime.now().isoformat())

    home_dict={}
    key_list=['bds','ba','sqft','acres']

    col_list=['acres', 'address', 'ba', 'bds', 'last_update', 'price', 'sqft',
           'zip_code']

    for x in range(len(detail_list)):

        for k in key_list:

            if k not in list(detail_list[x].keys()):

                detail_list[x][k]=-1

        # adding price data

        detail_list[x]['price']=price_list[x]

        # adding address

        detail_list[x]['address']=address_list[x]

        # add zip code

        detail_list[x]['zip_code']=zip_code

        # add state

    #     detail_list[x]['state']=state


        # adding last update date

        detail_list[x]['last_update']=ts

        # removing commas from numeric fields
#         detail_list[x]['sqft']=int(str(detail_list[x]['sqft']).replace(",", ""))

#         detail_list[x]['acres']=int(str(detail_list[x]['acres']).replace(",", ""))
        
        detail_list[x]['sqft']=detail_list[x]['sqft']

        detail_list[x]['acres']=detail_list[x]['acres']

        # cast strings to int

#         detail_list[x]['ba']=int(str(detail_list[x]['ba']).replace(",", ""))

#         detail_list[x]['bds']=int(str(detail_list[x]['bds']).replace(",", ""))
        
        detail_list[x]['ba']=detail_list[x]['ba']

        detail_list[x]['bds']=detail_list[x]['bds']

        # filtering for list of columns
        detail_list[x] = {k: v for k, v in detail_list[x].items() if k in col_list}


        # sorting by key

        detail_list[x]=dict(sorted(detail_list[x].items()))
        
        # turn into dataframe

    property_df=pd.DataFrame(detail_list)
    
    driver.quit()
    
    return property_df



# only returns first 9 entries

property_details(zip_code=94014)
```

tried implementing suggestion

## UPDATE:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

zip_code=94016



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("chromedriver"), chrome_options=chrome_options)

    
zip_url = 'https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/'+str(zip_code)+'_rb/'

# waits between pulling data
time.sleep(np.random.randint(low=3, high=7, size=1)[0])

# opens website
driver.get(zip_url)

# getting page source data
tstsoup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)


# getting list of prices

price_parse=tstsoup.find_all('div',{'class':'list-card-price'})

price_list=[]

for x in range(len(price_parse)):

    price_list.append(int(sub(r'[^\d.]', '',price_parse[x].get_text())))

# get address

address_parse=tstsoup.find_all('address',{'class':'list-card-addr'})

# address_parse[0].get_text()

address_list=[]

for i in range(len(address_parse)):

    address_list.append(address_parse[i].get_text())

# get home details

main_data=tstsoup.find_all('ul',{'class':'list-card-details'})
detail_list=[]
for data in main_data:
    d={  i.text.split(" ")[1] : i.text.split(" ")[0] for i in data.find_all("li",class_="")   }
    detail_list.append(d)

# creating dict of property details    

ts=str(datetime.datetime.now().isoformat())

home_dict={}
key_list=['bds','ba','sqft','acres']

col_list=['acres', 'address', 'ba', 'bds', 'last_update', 'price', 'sqft',
       'zip_code']

for x in range(len(detail_list)):

    for k in key_list:

        if k not in list(detail_list[x].keys()):

            detail_list[x][k]=-1

    # adding price data

    detail_list[x]['price']=price_list[x]

    # adding address

    detail_list[x]['address']=address_list[x]

    # add zip code

    detail_list[x]['zip_code']=zip_code

    # add state

#     detail_list[x]['state']=state


    # adding last update date

    detail_list[x]['last_update']=ts

    # removing commas from numeric fields
#         detail_list[x]['sqft']=int(str(detail_list[x]['sqft']).replace(",", ""))

#         detail_list[x]['acres']=int(str(detail_list[x]['acres']).replace(",", ""))

    detail_list[x]['sqft']=detail_list[x]['sqft']

    detail_list[x]['acres']=detail_list[x]['acres']

    # cast strings to int

#         detail_list[x]['ba']=int(str(detail_list[x]['ba']).replace(",", ""))

#         detail_list[x]['bds']=int(str(detail_list[x]['bds']).replace(",", ""))

    detail_list[x]['ba']=detail_list[x]['ba']

    detail_list[x]['bds']=detail_list[x]['bds']

    # filtering for list of columns
    detail_list[x] = {k: v for k, v in detail_list[x].items() if k in col_list}


    # sorting by key

    detail_list[x]=dict(sorted(detail_list[x].items()))
    
    print('made it')
    print('')

    # add scrolling

    actions = ActionChains(driver)

    footer = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div#region-info-footer')
    #if element is existing on the page the list will be non-empty and interpreted as True by python`
    if(footer):
        if not footer[0].is_displayed():
            #scroll the last currently available price_parse element into view. 
            #this will load a bulk of new elements
            actions.move_to_element(price_parse[-1]).perform()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            
            print('footer')
        else:
            #you can also use this case to exit the loop since you already scraped all the data on this page
            
            print('break')
            break
    else:        
        #if footer element is even not existing we 100% still not reached the bottom
        actions.move_to_element(price_parse[-1]).perform()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('scroll')

    # turn into dataframe
    
    
    print(len(detail_list))
```

exits at the break statement, doesn't scroll

UPDATE:

code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

zip_code=94014



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("chromedriver"), chrome_options=chrome_options)

    
zip_url = 'https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/'+str(zip_code)+'_rb/'

# waits between pulling data
time.sleep(np.random.randint(low=3, high=7, size=1)[0])

# opens website
driver.get(zip_url)

# getting page source data
tstsoup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)


# getting list of prices

price_parse=tstsoup.find_all('div',{'class':'list-card-price'})

price_list=[]

for x in range(len(price_parse)):

    price_list.append(int(sub(r'[^\d.]', '',price_parse[x].get_text())))

# get address

address_parse=tstsoup.find_all('address',{'class':'list-card-addr'})

# address_parse[0].get_text()

address_list=[]

for i in range(len(address_parse)):

    address_list.append(address_parse[i].get_text())

# get home details

main_data=tstsoup.find_all('ul',{'class':'list-card-details'})
detail_list=[]
for data in main_data:
    d={  i.text.split(" ")[1] : i.text.split(" ")[0] for i in data.find_all("li",class_="")   }
    detail_list.append(d)

# creating dict of property details    

ts=str(datetime.datetime.now().isoformat())

home_dict={}
key_list=['bds','ba','sqft','acres']

col_list=['acres', 'address', 'ba', 'bds', 'last_update', 'price', 'sqft',
       'zip_code']

for x in range(len(detail_list)):

    for k in key_list:

        if k not in list(detail_list[x].keys()):

            detail_list[x][k]=-1

    # adding price data

    detail_list[x]['price']=price_list[x]

    # adding address

    detail_list[x]['address']=address_list[x]

    # add zip code

    detail_list[x]['zip_code']=zip_code

    # add state

#     detail_list[x]['state']=state


    # adding last update date

    detail_list[x]['last_update']=ts

    # removing commas from numeric fields
#         detail_list[x]['sqft']=int(str(detail_list[x]['sqft']).replace(",", ""))

#         detail_list[x]['acres']=int(str(detail_list[x]['acres']).replace(",", ""))

    detail_list[x]['sqft']=detail_list[x]['sqft']

    detail_list[x]['acres']=detail_list[x]['acres']

    # cast strings to int

#         detail_list[x]['ba']=int(str(detail_list[x]['ba']).replace(",", ""))

#         detail_list[x]['bds']=int(str(detail_list[x]['bds']).replace(",", ""))

    detail_list[x]['ba']=detail_list[x]['ba']

    detail_list[x]['bds']=detail_list[x]['bds']

    # filtering for list of columns
    detail_list[x] = {k: v for k, v in detail_list[x].items() if k in col_list}


    # sorting by key

    detail_list[x]=dict(sorted(detail_list[x].items()))
    
    print('made it')
    print('')

    # add scrolling

    actions = ActionChains(driver)

    footer = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div#region-info-footer')
    #if element is existing on the page the list will be non-empty and interpreted as True by python`
    if(footer):
        if not footer[0].is_displayed():
            #scroll the last currently available price_parse element into view. 
            #this will load a bulk of new elements
            actions.move_to_element(price_parse[-1]).perform()
            
            # waits between pulling data
            time.sleep(np.random.randint(low=3, high=7, size=1)[0])
            
            print('footer')
        else:
            #you can also use this case to exit the loop since you already scraped all the data on this page
            
            print('break')
#             break
    else:        
        #if footer element is even not existing we 100% still not reached the bottom
        actions.move_to_element(price_parse[-1]).perform()
        
        # waits between pulling data
        time.sleep(np.random.randint(low=3, high=7, size=1)[0])
        
        print('scroll')

    # turn into dataframe
    
    
    print(len(detail_list))
    
    print(detail_list)
    print('')
```

output:

```
made it

break
9
[{'acres': -1, 'address': '543 Green Ridge Dr APT 4, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 898000, 'sqft': '1,443', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'bds': '2', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '940'}, {'bds': '2', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,394'}, {'bds': '2', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,158'}, {'bds': '3', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,640'}, {'bds': '3', 'ba': '3', 'sqft': '1,472'}, {'bds': '4', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,770'}, {'bds': '2', 'ba': '1', 'sqft': '560'}, {'bds': '4', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,770'}]

made it

break
9
[{'acres': -1, 'address': '543 Green Ridge Dr APT 4, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 898000, 'sqft': '1,443', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '340 San Diego Ave, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 870000, 'sqft': '940', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'bds': '2', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,394'}, {'bds': '2', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,158'}, {'bds': '3', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,640'}, {'bds': '3', 'ba': '3', 'sqft': '1,472'}, {'bds': '4', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,770'}, {'bds': '2', 'ba': '1', 'sqft': '560'}, {'bds': '4', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,770'}]

made it

break
9
[{'acres': -1, 'address': '543 Green Ridge Dr APT 4, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 898000, 'sqft': '1,443', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '340 San Diego Ave, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 870000, 'sqft': '940', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '691 Pointe Pacific Dr #4701, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 854000, 'sqft': '1,394', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'bds': '2', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,158'}, {'bds': '3', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,640'}, {'bds': '3', 'ba': '3', 'sqft': '1,472'}, {'bds': '4', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,770'}, {'bds': '2', 'ba': '1', 'sqft': '560'}, {'bds': '4', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,770'}]

made it

break
9
[{'acres': -1, 'address': '543 Green Ridge Dr APT 4, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 898000, 'sqft': '1,443', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '340 San Diego Ave, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 870000, 'sqft': '940', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '691 Pointe Pacific Dr #4701, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 854000, 'sqft': '1,394', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '535 Mountain View Dr APT 8, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 749000, 'sqft': '1,158', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'bds': '3', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,640'}, {'bds': '3', 'ba': '3', 'sqft': '1,472'}, {'bds': '4', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,770'}, {'bds': '2', 'ba': '1', 'sqft': '560'}, {'bds': '4', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,770'}]

made it

break
9
[{'acres': -1, 'address': '543 Green Ridge Dr APT 4, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 898000, 'sqft': '1,443', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '340 San Diego Ave, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 870000, 'sqft': '940', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '691 Pointe Pacific Dr #4701, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 854000, 'sqft': '1,394', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '535 Mountain View Dr APT 8, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 749000, 'sqft': '1,158', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '157 Westlake Ave, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '3', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 998888, 'sqft': '1,640', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'bds': '3', 'ba': '3', 'sqft': '1,472'}, {'bds': '4', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,770'}, {'bds': '2', 'ba': '1', 'sqft': '560'}, {'bds': '4', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,770'}]

made it

break
9
[{'acres': -1, 'address': '543 Green Ridge Dr APT 4, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 898000, 'sqft': '1,443', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '340 San Diego Ave, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 870000, 'sqft': '940', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '691 Pointe Pacific Dr #4701, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 854000, 'sqft': '1,394', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '535 Mountain View Dr APT 8, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 749000, 'sqft': '1,158', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '157 Westlake Ave, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '3', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 998888, 'sqft': '1,640', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '17 Honeysuckle Ct, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '3', 'bds': '3', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 1049888, 'sqft': '1,472', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'bds': '4', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,770'}, {'bds': '2', 'ba': '1', 'sqft': '560'}, {'bds': '4', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,770'}]

made it

break
9
[{'acres': -1, 'address': '543 Green Ridge Dr APT 4, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 898000, 'sqft': '1,443', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '340 San Diego Ave, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 870000, 'sqft': '940', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '691 Pointe Pacific Dr #4701, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 854000, 'sqft': '1,394', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '535 Mountain View Dr APT 8, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 749000, 'sqft': '1,158', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '157 Westlake Ave, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '3', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 998888, 'sqft': '1,640', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '17 Honeysuckle Ct, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '3', 'bds': '3', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 1049888, 'sqft': '1,472', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '314 E Moltke St, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '4', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 1250000, 'sqft': '1,770', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'bds': '2', 'ba': '1', 'sqft': '560'}, {'bds': '4', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,770'}]

made it

break
9
[{'acres': -1, 'address': '543 Green Ridge Dr APT 4, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 898000, 'sqft': '1,443', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '340 San Diego Ave, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 870000, 'sqft': '940', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '691 Pointe Pacific Dr #4701, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 854000, 'sqft': '1,394', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '535 Mountain View Dr APT 8, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 749000, 'sqft': '1,158', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '157 Westlake Ave, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '3', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 998888, 'sqft': '1,640', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '17 Honeysuckle Ct, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '3', 'bds': '3', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 1049888, 'sqft': '1,472', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '314 E Moltke St, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '4', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 1250000, 'sqft': '1,770', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '172 Hillcrest Dr, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '1', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 755000, 'sqft': '560', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'bds': '4', 'ba': '2', 'sqft': '1,770'}]

made it

break
9
[{'acres': -1, 'address': '543 Green Ridge Dr APT 4, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 898000, 'sqft': '1,443', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '340 San Diego Ave, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 870000, 'sqft': '940', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '691 Pointe Pacific Dr #4701, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 854000, 'sqft': '1,394', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '535 Mountain View Dr APT 8, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 749000, 'sqft': '1,158', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '157 Westlake Ave, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '3', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 998888, 'sqft': '1,640', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '17 Honeysuckle Ct, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '3', 'bds': '3', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 1049888, 'sqft': '1,472', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '314 E Moltke St, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '4', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 1250000, 'sqft': '1,770', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '172 Hillcrest Dr, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '1', 'bds': '2', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 755000, 'sqft': '560', 'zip_code': 94014}, {'acres': -1, 'address': '309 E Moltke St, Daly City, CA 94014', 'ba': '2', 'bds': '4', 'last_update': '2021-07-26T21:32:21.259987', 'price': 1199000, 'sqft': '1,770', 'zip_code': 94014}]
```

Comment: `zillow` is answered a ton! you don't need selenium even! check https://stackoverflow.com/a/68312200/7658985

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη thank you, your link looks just like what I'm looking for.  how do I modify the params argument to pull based on zipcode?

Comment: @user3476463 did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you Selenium approach. Scroll until footer element is visible.
Something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)

def property_details(zip_code):

#here comes all your code
------------------
-----------------
#after it just add this:
footer = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div#region-info-footer')
#if element is existing on the page the list will be non-empty and interpreted as True by python`
if(footer):
    if not footer[0].is_displayed():
        #scroll the last currently available price_parse element into view. 
        #this will load a bulk of new elements
        actions.move_to_element(price_parse[-1]).perform()
        time.sleep(0.5)
    else:
        #you can also use this case to exit the loop since you already scraped all the data on this page
        break
else:        
    #if footer element is even not existing we 100% still not reached the bottom
    actions.move_to_element(price_parse[-1]).perform()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  I tried implementing it.  I added an update to my original post where I tried your suggestion.  it seems to be exiting at the break statement without scrolling.  is there something I missed, did I implement it in correctly?

Comment: What if just not use that break? Do you have any other case to exit the loop? Try removing that else with the break and see if it works

Comment: I tried commenting out the break.  It ran a few times but before I could change the code to examine the output from each loop, zillow is now hitting me with captcha right after google chrome tries to launch a browser.  any tip on how to deal with that?

Comment: Nope, I have no idea how to overcome this. And this is definitely a new, additional question. So I think I answered this question as good as possible. So please accept this answer.

Comment: It seems that if I wait a while I can run the code again without getting hit with captcha.  so there must be some kind of limit per hour.  I've posted another update to my original post where I've tried combining your code with mine.  It doesn't seem to be scrolling the sidebar to pull in the new properties.  Instead it seems to mix in one or two different