# modify params in request to scrape zillow data using zip code

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape zillow home sale data.

I found the code below in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68311510/python-bs4-scraper-only-returning-first-9-results-from-each-page/68312200#68312200). It is scraping based on **county** and **state**, and what looks like maybe **gps coordinates** (mapBounds).

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        req.head("https://www.zillow.com/")
        for item in range(1, 2):
            # item can be used here to loop by refactoring `cat1` to be `cat2` and so on
            params = {
                "searchQueryState": '{"pagination":{"currentPage":2},"usersSearchTerm":"Orange County, CA","mapBounds":{"west":-118.84559473828126,"east":-116.68678126171876,"south":33.34208982842918,"north":33.99173886991076},"regionSelection":[{"regionId":1286,"regionType":4}],"isMapVisible":true,"filterState":{"isAllHomes":{"value":true},"sortSelection":{"value":"globalrelevanceex"}},"isListVisible":true,"mapZoom":9}',
                "wants": '{"cat1":["mapResults"]}',
            }
            r = req.get(url, params=params)
            df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()["cat1"]["searchResults"]["mapResults"])
            print(df)
            df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)


main("https://www.zillow.com/search/GetSearchPageState.htm")
```

Does anyone know how I can modify the params in the code below to query based on **zip code**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the zip code as the `userSearchTerm`, however, to get any kind of results you first need the `mapBounds` value filled in. How? You can get approximate GPS coordinates for US zip codes from Google Maps API, for example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=99501&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

For `99501`, which is Anchorage, AK, US, you should get something like this:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "99501",
               "short_name" : "99501",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Anchorage",
               "short_name" : "Anchorage",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Anchorage",
               "short_name" : "Anchorage",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Alaska",
               "short_name" : "AK",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Anchorage, AK 99501, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 61.246127,
                  "lng" : -149.7783468
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 61.19960589999999,
                  "lng" : -149.9247561
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 61.2189229,
               "lng" : -149.8503728
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 61.246127,
                  "lng" : -149.7783468
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 61.19960589999999,
                  "lng" : -149.9247561
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJH9xDEiSWyFYRzMdW-mWKwnk",
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Then you can use the coordiatates to make a request against zillow API.

For example:

```py
import json
import urllib.parse

import requests

link = 'https://www.zillow.com/search/GetSearchPageState.htm?'

params = {
    'searchQueryState': {
        "pagination": {},
        "usersSearchTerm": "99501",
        "mapBounds": {
                "west": -149.9247561,
                "east": -149.7783468,
                "south": 61.1996058,
                "north": 61.2461278,
        },
        "isListVisible": True,
        "mapZoom": 11
    },
    'wants': {"cat1": ["listResults"]},
    'requestId': 2
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) ' \
                              'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
                              'Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    data = json.loads(s.get(f"{link}{urllib.parse.urlencode(params)}").content)
    print(data["categoryTotals"]["cat1"])
```

This should give you:

```
{'totalResultCount': 223}
```

However, this is about a 100 results off from what you would get via the webpage.

[image]

But... if you add this line:

```
        "regionSelection": [{"regionId": 100220, "regionType": 7}],
```

to the payload, you'll get this:

```
{'totalResultCount': 113}
```

Caveat: I took the `regionSelection` line from the `XHR` tab of my browser's Developer Tools. I don't know (yet) where and how zillow assigns these values.

Final code:

```py
import json
import urllib.parse

import requests

link = 'https://www.zillow.com/search/GetSearchPageState.htm?'

params = {
    'searchQueryState': {
        "pagination": {},
        "usersSearchTerm": "99501",
        "mapBounds": {
                "west": -149.9247561,
                "east": -149.7783468,
                "south": 61.1996058,
                "north": 61.2461278,
        },
        "regionSelection": [{"regionId": 100220, "regionType": 7}],
        "isListVisible": True,
        "mapZoom": 11
    },
    'wants': {"cat1": ["listResults"]},
    'requestId': 2
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) ' \
                              'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
                              'Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    data = json.loads(s.get(f"{link}{urllib.parse.urlencode(params)}").content)
    print(data["categoryTotals"]["cat1"])
```

Comment: thank you for getting back to me with this suggestion.  I tried creating a google api key to pull the geocode data.  It appears to require a paid service from google to download geo location data, is that correct?  If not can you please tell me how to get a free api key to download the geo location data associated with the zip code?  Or do you know where to download geo location data for zip codes for free?

Comment: And no, I don' t know how to get that data for free. There's a three-month trail on Google Cloud so you might want to use that.